# Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type. react svg

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i want to inject an onclick function in a dynamic svg code.
and here is my code example.
‍‍‍

```
function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState("red");
  const [image, setimage] = useState(null);

  const fill = () => {
    alert(1);
    setColor("green");
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://file.qwertygo.com/media/image/cyan_qWYARBm.svg")
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setimage(
          [
            data.substring(0, data.search("currentcolor") + 13),
            ` onclick="fill()" `,
            data.substring(data.search("currentcolor") + 13)
          ].join("")
        );
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {image && (
        <SVG
          src={image}
          onClick={() => alert("green")}
          style={{
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
            position: "absolute",
            color: color,
            background: "#000"
          }}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[example](https://codesandbox.io/s/svg-test-bqdbw?file=/src/App.js:561-576)

when i click on the svg it says:
`` Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type. ``

and i want to run a function like `fill`
how should i do that?

Comment: you should paste code here. no deep link please

Comment: I've added code to the post @development-ninja

Comment: onClick={this.fill} doesn't work?

Comment: no, the problem is we are trying to use a string to pass a function and the error is true, my question is how to do that if we really want it?